# paste command with file headers

Tags: file, unix, command, paste

I have 178 files with an extension _count and I want to use paste command with the name of the file as the header, say

File1_count

```
abc
def 
gfh
```

FILE2_count

```
ijk
lmn
opq
```

FILE3_count

```
 rst
 uvw
 xyz
```

....
FILE178_count

```
 123
 456
 789
```

such that when I do 
paste *_count
I will get the headers with the paste command as

```
 FILE1 FILE2  FILE3   ....  FILE178
  abc    ijk    rst            123
  def    lmn    uvw            456
  gfh    opq    xyz            789
```

Comment: you'll have to rewrite (or make temp copies) to include the fileName as the header. `for f in FILE* ; do { echo "$f" ; cat $f  ; } >$f.tmp && mv $f.tmp $f` amd then your paste cmd. I think file1 file11 file111 will be the first 3 columns (for example), so better check that out first. You'll need to renamed files as `file0001` to get a clean list Good luck.

Comment: do you still need help with this? Good luck.

Comment: Hi shelter it worked! Although since it wasn't in answer section I could not mark it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to rewrite (or make temp copies) to include the fileName as the header. `for f in FILE* ; do { echo "$f" ; cat $f  ; } >$f.tmp && mv $f.tmp $f` amd then your paste cmd. I think file1 file11 file111 will be the first 3 columns (for example), so better check that out first. You'll need to renamed files as `file0001` to get a clean list Good luck.
                    – shellter

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a shell like `bash` that supports arrays, you can put all the files you care about in one, and print out it separated by tabs for the header and then call `paste` with the files in the array:

```sh
files=( *_count )
( IFS=$'\t'; printf "%s\n" "${files[*]%_count}"; paste "${files[@]}" ) > output.tsv
```

Comment: Late response, but another question was marked as a duplicate of this one, so it seemed like a better place to answer.